# How to get only User's from a Group that contains nested Groups using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get all unique user email addresses from a Distribution List (including all email addresses found in Nested DL's)

Is there a way to just return a list of all Microsoft.Graph.User's from a Nested DL and not include the Microsoft.Graph.Groups (i.e. filter to only include Users)?

I am currently flattening the nested DL's using `.TransitiveMembers` to get the group members from all levels.

The return of the distribution List query is a collection of Directory Objects. (in this case Groups and Users)

In my code, I cast to type User to have access to the User email address.

```
List<string> userMail = new List<string>();

var distList = await graphClient
       .Groups[$"{distributionListId}"]
       .TransitiveMembers
       .Request()
       .GetAsync();

foreach(User member in distList) {

   userMail.Add(member.Mail);

}
```

I expect that the query will run and return a list of Microsoft.Graph.Users and then I can iterate over them and get the email address that I want.

However, it crashes if distList contains a Microsoft.Graph.Group Object due to the cast in my foreach loop.

**Update**

I have updated the code to the following:

```
foreach (User member in distList.Where(x => x.ODataType.Contains("user"))) {

  userMail.Add(member.Mail)

}
```

This works but ideally I would like to avoid hard-coded strings like "user" in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enumerable.OfType` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) could be utilized to filter members by user type, like this:

```
var members = await graphClient
              .Groups[$"{distributionListId}"]
              .TransitiveMembers
              .Request()
              .GetAsync();

//filter members by user type
var users = members.OfType<Microsoft.Graph.User>();
foreach (var user in users)
{
   Console.WriteLine(user.Mail);
}
```